# Svelte component executes variable initialization unexpectedly

Tags: svelte

I am seeing strange behavior that I can't duplicate in a simpler component. Not knowing the inner workings of Svelte leaves me with a lack of troubleshooting tools.

Basically, what I'm seeing is that when an async function is called, the components variables are reinitialized. Here's a simplified excerpt:

```js
<script>
export let translation = {}
let edit = false

$: console.log(`edit=${edit}`)

async function translate() {
  edit = true
  await update(translation)
}
</script>

<button on:click={translate}>translate</button>
```

When the button is clicked, I see the following in the console:

```
edit='false'
edit='true'
edit='false'
```

Edit 2020-09-18

After further troubleshooting, I identified the root cause. A component higher in the hierarchy conditionally removes all child components while waiting for XHR calls. This is triggered by the async function call. So the question now becomes, how to write this component so it is immune to being reinitialized?

Comment: Really difficult to help with only this code snippet that is working just fine.

Comment: I don’t know is this related to your problem, but if I hit the button multiple times `wait()` is executed only once. I changed the code to `return new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>r(),ms));’ and now it executes as many times as I hit the button.

Comment: Vote to close it since it's not reproducible.

Comment: You should probably create a new question for the edited part!